# How to implement VGA Controller for Changing Background Color in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, vga

I'm a beginner VHDL coder. For just fun, I'm trying to implement the `640x480 @60Hz` VGA controller with Basys 2 Spartan-3E FPGA Trainer Board. My goal is to make background-color other than black and put 2 rectangles with a different color compared to the background. However, what I obtained is as follows:
[image]

What can be the problem?

The related part of the VHDL code as follows:

```
draw: process(clk25,RST,hPos,vPos,videoOn)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        RGB <= "00000000";
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 ='1') then

        if(videoOn <= '1') then
            if((hPos>=10 and hPos <=60) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60) )then
                RGB <= "11111111";

            elsif((hPos>=70 and hPos <= 120) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60 ) )then
                RGB <= "11111110";
            else
                RGB <= "00000011";  
            end if;
        else
            RGB <= "00000000";
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

The whole code as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity vga_driver is
    Port ( CLK   : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RST   : in  STD_LOGIC;
           HSYNC : out  STD_LOGIC;
           VSYNC : out  STD_LOGIC;
           RGB   : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0));
end vga_driver;

architecture Behavioral of vga_driver is

signal clk25 : std_logic := '0';

constant HD  : integer := 639;  -- Horizontal Display
constant HFP : integer := 16;   -- Right border (front)
constant HSP : integer := 96;     -- Sync pulse (retrace)
constant HBP : integer := 48;   -- Left border (back    porch)

constant VD  : integer := 479;  -- Horizontal Display
constant VFP : integer := 10;   -- Right border (front)
constant VSP : integer := 2;      -- Sync pulse (retrace)
constant VBP : integer := 33;   -- Left border (back    porch)

signal hPos: integer := 0;
signal vPos: integer := 0;

signal videoOn: std_logic := '0';
signal frameCounter: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);


begin

clk_div: process(CLK)
begin
    if(CLK'event and CLK = '1')then
        clk25 <= not clk25;
    end if ;
end process;

Horizontal_pos_counter:process(clk25,RST)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then 
        hPos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25 'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos = HD + HFP + HSP + HBP) then
            hPos <= 0; 
        else
            hPos <= hPos +1;
        end if;
    end if ;
end process;


Vertical_pos_counter:process(clk25,RST,hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then 
        vPos <= 0;
    elsif(clk25 'event and clk25 = '1')then
        if(hPos = (HD + HFP + HSP + HBP))then
            if(vPos = (VD + VFP + VSP + VBP)) then
                vPos <= 0; 
                if(frameCounter < "1111111111111111") then
                    frameCounter <= frameCounter+1;
                else
                    frameCounter <= (others => '0') ;
                end if;
            else
                vPos <= vPos +1;

            end if;
        end if;
    end if ;
end process;

Horizontal_Synchronisation:process(clk25,RST,hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        HSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1') then
        if((hPos <= (HD + HFP)) OR (hPos > (HD + HFP + HSP)))then
            HSYNC <= '1';
        else
            HSYNC <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;

Vertical_Synchronisation:process(clk25,RST,hPos)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        VSYNC <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 = '1') then
        if((vPos <= (VD + VFP)) OR (vPos > (VD + VFP + VSP))) then
            VSYNC <= '1';
        else
            VSYNC <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;

end process;

video_on: process(clk25,hPos,vPos,RST)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        videoOn <= '0';
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 ='1') then
        if(hPos <= HD and vPos <= VD) then
            videoOn <= '1';
        else
            videoOn <= '0';
        end if;
    end if;

end process;

draw: process(clk25,RST,hPos,vPos,videoOn)
begin
    if(RST = '1') then
        RGB <= "00000000";
    elsif(clk25'event and clk25 ='1') then

        if(videoOn <= '1') then
            if((hPos>=10 and hPos <=60) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60) )then
                RGB <= "11111111";
            elsif((hPos>=70 and hPos <= 120) AND (vPos>=10 and vPos <=60 ) )then
                RGB <= "11111110";
            else
                RGB <= "00000011";  
            end if;
        else
            RGB <= "00000000";
        end if;

    end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: _What can be the problem?_ is a non-specific problem statement. Are you asking about the apparent horizontal shift to the right and ragged edges of the two rectangular areas or why the colors are the same (and the background is black as well)?  The former is dependent on your monitor interface and video timing, the latter on mapping the RGB value to colors for the monitor. These appear to be electronics questions concerning connections to the monitor and not related to your VHDL description should the constants be correct.

Comment: Closer examination ([with a testbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kepa5.jpg)) shows rgb never has a value "00000000" during blanking (videoOn = '0'). This can affect color value clamping with an analog monitor. It's not clear if that would also affect horizontal sync position detection. It may actually be worth getting the blanking color set properly in process draw. `if(videoOn <= '1') then` should use equality operator "=". In process video_on `if(hPos <= HD and vPos <= VD) then` should be `if hPos <= HD - 1 and vPos <= VD - 1 then` (conditions don't require parentheses in VHDL).

Comment: For binary in synthesis or in simulation `videoOn <= '1'` would be always true.

Comment: The image problem can't be replicated as it results from analog effects. This question belongs on [EE Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl+vga) and should show the monitor connection circuitry.

Comment: I asked this question in EE stack exchange. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Your suggestion actually works. Thanks

Comment: The R-2R ladders for the analog VGA RGB are found in Fig 13 of the [Basys 2 Reference Manual](https://reference.digilentinc.com/_media/basys2/tempk.png). Proving why it works requires a detailed examination of the monitor used. Why there is horizontal precession (and regression) isn't readily apparent. The Basys2 uses an [LTC6905-100](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6905xfa.pdf) clock source for it's 50 Mhz MCLK input. There's nothing in the datasheet to indicate why you'd be getting 40 ns of jitter. I'd suspect cabling to the monitor.

Comment: Your [simulation waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pOp1.png) shows clk_period 10000 ps (10 ns) which is 100 MHz presumably for CLK. Your clk_div process divides that by 2.  With a testbench clock period of 20 ns (50 MHz) I get a horizontal interval of 32.000 us (1600 clocks CLK periods, 800 CLK25 periods/pixels) which is correct. (The VGA clock should be 25.175 MHz to give 31.777557 us horizontal interval, 25 MHz is within 0.7 percent, should work.)  No jumper on JP4 on the Basys2 board should give 50 MHz CLK.

Comment: Thank you for your informative comments! As you assume clock_period 10ns. Yet, I didn't change the default clock frequency in the hardware (50MHz). Just for curiosity, how did you derive the number 0.7 percent?